# PHP: RSS feed does not validate with accented characters present

Tags: php, rss, feed, non-ascii-characters

I made my own rss feed with php, but I cannot get it validated when I use accented characters. I can't find a solution for that.

This is my RSS feed until now:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
        <channel>
        <title>My site</title>
        <link>http://www.example.com</link>
        <description>The newest music</description>
        <atom:link href="http://www.example.com/feed.php" rel="self"></atom:link>
        <item>
        <title><![CDATA[Beyoncé - Sorry]]></title>
        <description>New Music</description>
        <pubDate>Thu, 23 Jun 2016 09:07:10 +0000</pubDate>
        <guid>http://www.example.com/beyonce/sorry</guid>
        <enclosure url="mypicture.jpg" length="0" type="image/jpeg"></enclosure>
        <link>http://www.example.com/beyonce/sorry</link>
        </item>
        </channel>
    </rss>
```

I tried the CDATA tag, and it fixed special characters, but not the accented.
Any thoughts?

I used: https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi as validator.
Error message: "'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 2474: invalid continuation byte (maybe a high-bit character?)"

And I check in my Firefox and IE browsers, it just doesn't show the item with the accented character. Other items within the whole feed are displayed just fine.

This is the header info:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: It validates just fine for me. Are you using some sort of specific validation method? What's the error? Do provide with what *doesn't* work instead of just what does work.

Comment: I edited the post, to answer your questions.

Comment: I povided what does NOT work. The working items are removed from the code above.

Comment: Is your RSS stream UTF-8 ?

Comment: Yes: header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8'); is added on top of the page.

Comment: There's a subtle difference between the charset header and the actual character encoding. If you're storing your text in a file which is not stored in UTF-8 but then your're setting the header as UTF-8 you can still get this problem. Make sure all your process from start to end is UTF-8

Comment: But how do I do that? I just read data from mysql and generate the feed within a php file. I thought setting the header was enough?

Comment: If you have the text in code files, make sure they are saved as UTF-8, if you have data in your database make sure they're UTF-8 if you have data in other files, make sure they are saved as UTF-8.. you get the idea. Or your solution of doing a `utf8_encode` may work **if your initial encoding was ISO-8859-1** (which seems to be in your case, but it's not always true). Welcome to the hell of character encodings.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into my database to see!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

Make sure you use utf8_encode() to get the accented character right.

Example:

```
$title = Beyoncé;
$title = utf8_encode($title);

echo $title
```